# How to create a socket that constantly listen from the Server in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm doing a kind of Clock using Sockets with Java however I need that my client can interact with the Server changing the time. My main problem is: if I add any code for listen the Client, the Server Stop. I think I could use a thread or a async function nevertheless I'm totally new in Java and I don't know how to manipulate it.

These are my current codes:

server.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {

    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2000);
    Timer data = new Timer();

    while (true) {

        Socket s = ss.accept();

        ArrayList<Integer> time = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        data.updateTime();

        time.add(data.getHour());
        time.add(data.getMinute());
        time.add(data.getSecond());

        System.out.println(time.get(0) + ":" + time.get(1) + ":"
                + time.get(2));

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    s.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(time);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Timer.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Timer {
private int hour;
private int minute;
private int second;

public Timer() {
    this.hour = randInt(0, 23);
    this.minute = randInt(0, 59);
    this.second = randInt(0, 59);
}

public void changeTime(int hour, int minute, int second) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    // NOTE: Usually this should be a field rather than a method
    // variable so that it is not re-seeded every call.
    Random rand = new Random();

    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}

private void updateHour() {
    if (this.hour == 23)
        this.hour = 0;
    else
        this.hour++;
}

private void updateMinute() {
    if (this.minute == 59)
        this.minute = 0;
    else
        this.minute++;
}

private void updateSecond() {
    if (this.second == 59)
        this.second = 0;
    else
        this.second++;
}

public int getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public int getMinute() {
    return minute;
}

public int getSecond() {
    return second;
}

public void updateTime() {
    this.updateSecond();

    if (this.second == 0) {
        this.updateMinute();
        if (this.minute == 0)
            this.updateHour();
    }
}
}
```

And this is the Event Click where I'm trying to send the Data:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getSource() == startButton) {
        Socket s;
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 2000);
            InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    in, textField1.getText()));
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out,
                    textField1.getText()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }// we try to connect
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if any of you know what kind of Code I should add in the Server to continue sending the Time randomly created and to wait if there is any message from the client and if there is a message to change the time with the new one. Thanks in Advance for your help, and so sorry if it's a basic question but I'm really new with Sockets and Java.

Comment: Have a look at the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class to store your timer.

```
public class MyTimer(){
    private Timer t;
    public MyTimer(Timer t){
        this.t = t;
    }

    public synchronized Timer getTimer(){
        return t;
    }

    public synchronized void setTimer(Timer t){
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```

And in the server, you need to use an object from this class.

```
final MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer(new Timer());
```

In the first line in while loop, you can get the timer inside the myTimer to your data variable.

```
Timer data = myTimer.getTimer();
```

Before the while loop, start a new Thread to listen to the client so that you can update the timer in myTimer object.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            //Listen to the client if there is new time available
            //get new timer to a variable (here, newData)
            myTimer.setTimer(newData);
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Hi, @Ramesh-X, I did this changes as I thought you told me and it didn't work because the server didn't send me any information and when I tried to send a static value like in the event didn't work too.
server.java
http://pastebin.com/5drzwF6z

event
http://pastebin.com/gQA0R85b
Event error
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException

Comment: Do reading part in one thread and writing part in another thread. You have done both things in the same thread. Think that as, one thread is always sending the Timer, doesn't care reading. And other thread is only reading Timer, doesn't care about writing Timer..

Comment: In this new version I changed as a new thread I think, http://pastebin.com/8NLmxPxR because if I send something from the Client it stop for maybe a second sometimes and it gives me a strange error (right know I'm just trying to send some data), and this is the new event: http://pastebin.com/WpGAeHNK

But finally it gave me this bug:
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a dummy mistake from my part!